# How to upload file(>64M) to azure blob storage[iOS]

Tags: ios, azure, out-of-memory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using [WAToolkit](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios) to add blob to container,but when upload big file it will generate the error:Error Domain=com.microsoft.WAToolkit Code=413 "The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.".The remarks section of the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) indicates the maximum upload size for a block blob is 64 MB. The app may also receive memory warning.

```
    NSString *blobName = @"IMG_0242.MOV";
    WABlob *blob = [[[WABlob alloc] initBlobWithName:blobName  URL:nil containerName:self.selectedContainer.name] autorelease];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:blobName ofType:nil];
    blob.contentData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [storageClient addBlob:blob
                   toContainer:self.selectedContainer
         withCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
             if(error) {
                 NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                 return;
             }
         }];
    }];
```

How to change the code or use other method to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Azure Mobile Services (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/ios/) yet? WAToolkit is deprecated.

Comment: NO,Azure Mobile Services can't satisfy the demand. I need to use blob and queue storage. And the [Azure Storage client library](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/build-2015-azure-storage-announcements/) for iOS haven't released.

Comment: actually, you can use WAMS. See the following blog. While it isn't baked into the library yet, it is possible. http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage

Comment: I read that blog few months ago.It's implemented by node.js not native iOS .And we use Azure Storage not Mobile Services.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your file. Here a few links that could help you:

[Best way to upload a blob with a huge size in GBs to azure in the fastest time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892957/best-way-to-upload-a-blob-with-a-huge-size-in-gbs-to-azure-in-the-fastest-time)

http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/